# is there a way to attach a PDF FILE with Net::SMTP in Perl

Tags: perl, smtp, attachment

I'm trying to attach a pdf file on a multipart content email, yes I know i could use mime lite or a billion perl modules, but I'm limited to use perl 5.8.8 as it comes out of the box, so far I have

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Net::SMTP;
use MIME::Base64 qw( encode_base64 );
use MIME::Base64 qw( decode_base64 );
use strict;
use warnings;

my $from = 'az@xx.com';
my $to = 'raxxxfael.xx@xxx.com';
my $to2 = 'xx.xx@xxx.com';
my $boundary = 'frontier';




open my $Initial_File, '<', "summary.pdf";
binmode $Initial_File;
open my $Initial_OutFile, '>', "temp.pdf";
my $buf;
while ( read( $Initial_File, $buf, 60 * 57 ) ) {
    print $Initial_OutFile encode_base64( $buf );
}

close $Initial_OutFile;
close $Initial_File;


open INFILE, '<', "temp.pdf";
open my $final_output, '>',"summary2.pdf";
binmode $final_output;
my $buffer;
while ( $buffer = <INFILE> ) {
    print $final_output decode_base64( $buffer );
}
my @pdf = $final_output;
close $final_output;
close INFILE; 

my $smtp = Net::SMTP->new('xx.xxx.com');
$smtp->mail($from);
$smtp->recipient($to,$to2, { SkipBad => 1 });
$smtp->data();
$smtp->datasend("Subject: Test Email \n");
$smtp->datasend("MIME-Version: 1.0\n");
$smtp->datasend("Content-type: multipart/mixed;\n\tboundary=".$boundary."\n");
$smtp->datasend("\n");
$smtp->datasend("--".$boundary."\n");
$smtp->datasend("Content-type: text/plain\n");
$smtp->datasend("Content-Disposition: quoted-printable\n");
$smtp->datasend("\nTest From You \n");
$smtp->datasend("--".$boundary."\n");
$smtp->datasend("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=summary2.pdf \n");
$smtp->datasend("Content-Type: application/pdf; name=summary2.pdf ");
$smtp->datasend("\n");
$smtp->datasend("@pdf\n");
$smtp->datasend("--".$boundary."--\n");
$smtp->dataend();
# $smtp->quit;   

exit;
```

The email sends out correctly, but (obviously) when trying to open the pdf file it says it has an incorrect encoding, is there a way to buffer the PDF file to the attachment in a way that it send it out as it is ?

Comment: [MIME::Lite is pure-perl](http://deps.cpantesters.org/?module=MIME%3A%3ALite&perl=5.8.8&pureperl=on), just copy the code.

Comment: "I'm limited to use perl 5.8.8 as it comes out of the box" - That's probably the problem that you should be addressing first :-) If you can't use CPAN then you're really not using the full power of Perl.

Comment: @DaveCross completely agree, if it was up to me I would installed the whole CPAN already, this is a production server and IT in unwilling to make  even the slightest change.

Comment: @daxim thanks for the tip! i did that, if u want to set it as anser ill accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ended up adding MIME:Lite manually to my user directory

```
use lib '/xx/sas/xx/perl';
use MIME::Lite;
open(SMTP,'/xx/sas/xx/perl/MIME/srv.txt') || die("Could not open the file");
my $mail_host = <SMTP>;
close(SMTP);
open(DATA, $ARGV[3] ) || die("Could not open the file");
my @csv = <DATA>;
close(DATA);

foreach (@csv){
    $textStr.= $_;
}

$msg = MIME::Lite->new (
  From => $ARGV[0],
  To => $ARGV[1],
  Subject => $ARGV[2],
  Type =>'multipart/mixed'
) or die "Error creating multipart container: $!\n";

$msg->attach (
  Type => 'TEXT',
  Data => $textStr
) or die "Error adding the text message part: $!\n";

foreach my $file (split(',', $ARGV[4])) { 
        $content_type='TEXT';
        if ( $file =~ /\.gif$/i ){ $content_type ='image/gif'}
        if ( $file =~ /\.jpg$/i ){ $content_type ='image/jpeg'}
        if ( $file =~ /\.zip$/i ){ $content_type ='application/zip'}
        if ( $file =~ /\.html$/i ){ $content_type ='text/html'}
        if ( $file =~ /\.pdf$/i ){ $content_type ='application/pdf'}
        if ( $file =~ /\.xls$/i ){ $content_type ='application/vnd.ms-excel'}
        if ( $file =~ /\.log$/i ){ $content_type ='application/octet-stream'}
        $msg->attach (
           Type => $content_type,
           Path => $file,
           Filename => $file,
           Disposition => 'attachment'
        ) or die "Error adding $file: $!\n";    
}   

MIME::Lite->send('smtp', $mail_host, Timeout=>60);
$msg->send;
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working example of how to send multipart mail messages using Net::SMTP.

Code for sending plain text, a plain text file, and a binary image (jpg) are provided.

Hope this helps!

Alejandro

PS. The code RVS provided above lists several other content types, including a pdf. Anything that is not a plain text file should be considered a binary file and sent encoded as base64. You do not need to decode it, since the email client that receives the mail should take care of that.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Net::SMTP;
use strict;
use warnings;

use MIME::Base64 qw( encode_base64 );
#use MIME::Base64 qw( decode_base64 );

my $from = 'from@email.com';
my $to = 'to@email.com';

my $attachBinaryFile= 'test.jpg';
my $attachTextFile = 'test.txt';

my $boundary = 'frontier';

open(DAT, $attachTextFile) || die("Could not open text file!");
my @textFile = <DAT>;
close(DAT);

my $smtp = Net::SMTP->new('your.smtp.com', Timeout => 60) || die("Could not create SMTP object.");
print "Sending mail\n";
$smtp->mail($from);
$smtp->recipient($to, { SkipBad => 1 });
$smtp->data();
$smtp->datasend("To: $to\n");
$smtp->datasend("From: $from\n");
$smtp->datasend("Subject: Multi part test\n");
$smtp->datasend("MIME-Version: 1.0\n");
$smtp->datasend("Content-type: multipart/mixed;\n\tboundary=\"$boundary\"\n");
$smtp->datasend("\n");
$smtp->datasend("--$boundary\n");
$smtp->datasend("Content-type: text/plain\n");
$smtp->datasend("Content-Disposition: quoted-printable\n");
$smtp->datasend("\nToday\'s files are attached:\n");
$smtp->datasend("\nHave a nice day! :)\n");
$smtp->datasend("--$boundary\n");
$smtp->datasend("Content-Type: application/text; name=\"$attachTextFile\"\n");
$smtp->datasend("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$attachTextFile\"\n");
$smtp->datasend("\n");
$smtp->datasend("@textFile\n");
$smtp->datasend("--$boundary\n");
$smtp->datasend("Content-Type: image/jpeg; name=\"$attachBinaryFile\"\n");
$smtp->datasend("Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n");
$smtp->datasend("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$attachBinaryFile\"\n");
$smtp->datasend("\n");
my $buf;
open(DAT, "../uploads/$attachBinaryFile") || die("Could not open binary file!");
   binmode(DAT);
   local $/=undef;
   while (read(DAT, my $picture, 4096)) {
      $buf = &encode_base64( $picture );
      $smtp->datasend($buf);
   }
close(DAT);
$smtp->datasend("\n");
$smtp->datasend("--$boundary\n");
$smtp->dataend();
$smtp->quit;
print "Mail sent\n";
exit;
```

Comment: Hello, I've used this code and seems to be working but I'm curious to the additional file that was also attached in the email which was not included on the code. Just wondering why or how it happens. Thank you! :D

Comment: The above solution is almost correct, except in chunk buffer size "4096" - this size is incorrect and will result in all text removed from the pdf or blank pdf. The correct size is "4104", as it must be a multiple of 57 bytes. I struggled with this until I've found the correct chunk size at the always incredible Perl Monks site: https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1211052

Answer (score 0):

This...looks wrong:

```
open FILE, "summary.pdf" or die $!;
my @txt = <FILE>;
close FILE;

...
$smtp->datasend("@txt\n");
```

I believe the problem you seek lies within these two lines of code.  You're reading a binary format with a string reader, and then having that binary interpolated into a string.

Try:

```
...
open FILE, "summary.pdf" or die $!;
binmode(FILE);
my $data = do { local $/; <FILE> };
close FILE;
...
$smtp->datasend($data);
```

or something along these lines.

Comment: Bummer!  I didn't try it, just said it might be in the right direction. :)